# How to pass an argument into call_user_func

Tags: php

Here is a line of code I am using:

```
$json[JsonConstant::JSON_CUSTOM] => call_user_func(array($this, $customTypes[$customDownloadType])),
```

`$customTypes[$customDownloadType]` might resolve to something like `getTags()`.

What do I do though, if I want to pass an argument to `getTags()` though? For example, say I have a var called `$time` that I want to pass in? What do I do?

It seems I want a mixture of examples 2 and 4 from http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php - is that possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
call_user_func($fn, 'a', 'b', 'c'); // => $fn('a', 'b', 'c');

call_user_func_array($fn, ['a', 'b', 'c']); /// => $fn('a', 'b', 'c');
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, you don't need the `array($this,` part.

The code snippet confuses me a bit because it looks as if you should be using the assignment operator `=` instead of `=>` as you also specify an array key before hand...

However if that isn't the case, `$json[JsonConstant::JSON_CUSTOM] => call_user_func($customTypes[$customDownloadType], $time), ...` should work OK.

I also think that the `$customTypes[$customDownloadType]` would have to return `"getTags"` for example and not `"getTags()"` although I could be wrong.

You can also use variable functions instead: `$json[JsonConstant::JSON_CUSTOM] => $customTypes[$customDownloadType]($time), ...`

Regards